# Frequent WebThread Crash on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios11

Does anynone know how to fix this issue? There are so many crashes posted to Fabric, which only appeared on iOS 11. Fabric gives a tip:

> This crash has non-main threads that appear to use UIKit classes or functions. Generally speaking, it is only safe to use UIKit from the main thread. Calling into UIKit from background threads can cause unpredictable behavior (like crashes!). Please double check that all of your code (that is not on the main thread) has been explicitly marked as safe to use in the background by Apple.

Below is the crash session:

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1845041a0 objc_retain + 16
1  UIKit                          0x18e850a10 -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] + 76
2  UIKit                          0x18eb4416c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 72
3  UIKit                          0x18e856e60 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1348
4  QuartzCore                     0x1892e3948 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
5  QuartzCore                     0x1892e7ad0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332
6  QuartzCore                     0x18925431c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336
7  QuartzCore                     0x18927bb40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
8  QuartzCore                     0x18927c980 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
9  CoreFoundation                 0x185246cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
10 CoreFoundation                 0x185244694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
11 CoreFoundation                 0x185164c78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 468
12 WebCore                        0x18d0d984c RunWebThread(void*) + 560
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ec82b4 _pthread_body + 308
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ec8180 _pthread_body + 310
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184ec6b74 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: All the interface elements bars, views( text, graphics, animations), controls (Buttons, switches, text fields, and progress indicators) must be updated in the main thread. Please check your code you are not updating any of these elements in background thread by mistake